# Finding string in given set of strings bt comma separated

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, substring

I need to get third sub string from a string below are the samples, using SQL Server 2008.

**string1:-**

```
('C20080703115333MCTTtettett','24','6101349328','Bundled Standard','4','2.00','Testing Insert for New SP',','PD2013021002584832540')
```

**desired result:-** `6101349328`

**string2:-**

```
('C20080703115333MCTTetew','24','7101349328','Bundled Standard','4','2.00','Testing Insert for New SP',','PD2013021002584832540')
```

**desired result:-** `7101349328`

**string3:-**

```
('C20080703115333MCTTteetew','24tt','8101349328','Bundled Standard','4','2.00','Testing Insert for New SP',','PD2013021002584832540')
```

**desired result:-** `8101349328`

**string4:-**

```
('C20080703','24','111101349328','Bundled Standard','4','2.00','Testing Insert for New SP',','PD2013021002584832540')
```

**desired result:-** `111101349328`

Thanks In advance.

Comment: [What have **you** tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: That looks more like getting the third column, not the third substring...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
select val = substring
  (
    str
    , charindex(',', str, charindex(',',str, 0) + 1) + 2
    , charindex(',', str, charindex(',', str, charindex(',',str, 0) + 1) + 1)
       - (charindex(',', str, charindex(',',str, 0) + 1) + 3)
  )
from strings
```

Which gives:

```
6101349328
7101349328
8101349328
111101349328
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/494ac/1).